# name for derangement with unique neighbors

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

If a row of people must reorder themselves so that nobody is sitting in the same seat as before, that's a derangement. Is there a name for the derangement wherein no person in their new seat is has the same neighbors as before? I would have called this a [double derangement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354946/double-derangement) but that refers to a property of two derangements of a given set, the each being a derangement of the other and of the original ordering.

Consider derangements of $123456$:

- $234561$ has almost all the same neighbors (256 of these)
- $635142$ has no
  element near another (27 of these)
- $351642$ also has no element
  formerly on the end still at the end (19 of these)
- $314625$ can be
  arranged in a circle and not have the same neighbors (18 of these)

Comment: First step, check OEIS: https://oeis.org/A288208. The only reference is this other MSE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309850. It is safe to say this concept has not been researched much, so I am pretty sure there is no widely used name.

Comment: OK, now I see how useful OEIS can be! Thanks for the reminder @MikeEarnest.